# Property 'name' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using [flight radar api](https://rapidapi.com/apidojo/api/flight-radar1/) to create a simple application. I store the results of the Api call in state like this

```
  const [airports, setAirports] = useState([]);
```

airports is an **array of objects**.

When I try to log out an airport name like this

```
airports.map(airport => console.log(airport.name));
```

I get an error in Vs that **Property 'name' does not exist on type 'never'.**

I'm new to Typescript I have no idea how to solve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to explicitly tell the type of `airports` like this:

```
const [airports, setAirports] = useState<Airport[]>([]);
```

Right now in your code, typescript is inferring `airports` to be `never[]`, hence the error.